# Make a custom class of UIPickerView able to send events in Swift

Tags: swift3, uipickerview, uidatepicker, uicontrol, uicontrolevents

I've written a custom class based on `UIPickerView`. Within a class I implemented next method:

```
func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

    let min = (selectedRow(inComponent: 0) % minutes.count)
    let sec = (selectedRow(inComponent: 1) % seconds.count)

    self.min = min
    self.sec = sec

    }
```

Every time user has selected value from "min" and "sec" using picker view, these class variables are changed accordingly. So, it's work ok.

Now, I would like this class to send event every time these variables are changed. Is it possible to adopt `valueChanged` event for this class, and how to implement it, or I have to make custom event for these purposes? I would like to do it in that way to be able making action outlets via IB. Please, correct me if I missed the pattern.

May be I put this question in other words: what makes the build-in `UIDataPicker` able to connect to view controller within interface builder with actions outlets - and what should I add to my custom class to achieve partially that functionality?

Apple stated that: "`UIDatePicker` class uses a custom subclass of `UIPickerView` to display dates and times." Correct me here if I'm wrong, but they also point out that `UIDatePicker` inherits from `UIControl` rather than from `UIPickerView`. As for `UIPickerView` - they say it inherits from the `UIView`. So, I see no connection in terms of inheritance of `UIControl` for `UIPickerView` and `UIDatePicker`. Also I can't inherit `UIControl` to obtain event sending functionality due to multiple inheritance of `UIView` class. Can't understand why things here so weird and I can't use `UIControl` functionality for `UIPickerView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create `YourCustomControl` inherit from `UIControl`
2. addSubview `UIPickerView`
3. set `YourCustomControl` as a delegate for this picker

[image]

To send event you need add this line

```
sendActions(for: .valueChanged)
```

in every place where these variables are changed

[UIKit - sendActions](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618211-sendactions)

Comment: `var min: Int = 0 { didSet { sendActions(for: .valueChanged) } }` - but no luck:  unresolved identifier 'sendActions'. In my DataPicker class I inherit `UIPickerView`, `UIPickerViewDataSource`, `UIPickerViewDelegate`. I think I have to inherit one more class or protocol to make `sendActions` available?

Comment: Just find out that I have to inherit from `UIControl` class for using `sendActions..`. But I inherit already from `UIPickerView` and get the compile error - `Multiple inheritance from classes `UIControl` and `UIPickerView`. Is there any way to solve this contradiction and still use `UIPickerView`?

Comment: It was a bit concise answer for me at first, but after some time of experimenting I got the idea! Thank's a lot!